# What happens to the capacitance of a system if capacitors are charged in parallel and then put into a series circiut

Tags: capacitance

If you have 2 capacitors 2V, 2F each. When you charge them in parallel, the system will have 2V and 4F when you attach a load to it. If you take the charged capacitors and then put them in series, does the system just change to 4V, 1F? What happened to the other 3F? Why does this happen?

Comment: This is the operating principle of a [charge pump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_pump), if you didn't know already.

Answer (score 9):

Each capacitor stores energy which is conserved.  The energy stored in one of the capacitors is

$$\frac{1}{2}CV^2 = \frac{1}{2}(2\:\mathrm F) (2\:\mathrm V)^2 = 4\:\mathrm J$$

for a total of \$8\:\mathrm J\$ of stored energy.  Whether the capacitors are placed in parallel or series, the amount of energy stored is the same.

If the charged capacitors are placed in parallel appropriately, the voltage across the combination is \$2\:\mathrm V\$ and the energy stored is \$8\:\mathrm J\$.

Thus the equivalent capacitance is

$$C_\text{EQ} = 2\frac{8\:\mathrm J}{(2\:\mathrm V)^2} = 4\:\mathrm F$$

If the charged capacitors are placed in series appropriately, the voltage across the combination is 4V and the energy store is \$8\:\mathrm J\$.

Thus, the equivalent capacitance is

$$C_\text{EQ} = 2\frac{8\:\mathrm J}{(4\:\mathrm V)^2} = 1\:\mathrm F$$

Yes, there is a \$3\:\mathrm F\$ difference but asking "*what happened to the other 3 farads?*" is like asking "*what happened to the other 3 ohms?*" when comparing series and parallel connected 2 ohm resistors.

No capacitance has 'vanished'.  Both capacitors still have \$2\:\mathrm F\$ each of capacitance.  What has changed is the configuration of the capacitors and, thus, the *equivalent* capacitance as seen by an external circuit.

Comment: @KumaraswamyMudide: Yes, you can treat the two connected plates as having no effect on the series-conencted capacitor. In fact, you could reduce them to a single plate, or even eliminate them altogether -- BUT, and this is key -- you still have twice the dielectric thickness compared to one of the original capacitors. This means that you have half of the capacitance, and if the charge is the same, you also have twice the voltage.

Answer (score 2):

Put very simply, the capacitance of a capacitor is related to the area of its metal parts storing the charge and the distance between them:

$$ C = \epsilon A/d $$

Where

- \$A\$ is the area,
- \$d\$ is their distance, and
- \$\epsilon\$ is a constant.

Which means for the purpose of this simplified discussion we can ignore \$\epsilon\$.

I am going to leave out units, because I am too lazy at 4AM to add superscripts and what not.

If we have one capacitor with A = 2, d = 1, we get C = 2.
Now we add another capacitor next to it.
This makes the two capacitors a system with effectively twice that area.
So we "see" a capacitor of A = 4, but still d = 1, we get C = 4.

Now if we put one capacitor of A = 2 and d = 1 on top of another of A = 2 and d = 1, on the outside, the top most pin and the bottom most pin, we only see A = 2. We couldn't ever see anything other than A = 2, because our terminal has an area of 2.
But, by adding them together we made the total gap between the two pins d = 2.
So now we have a capacitor of A = 2 and d = 2, makes C = 1.

What little this means to charge and stored energy concerning Coulomb et.al. I leave to another as the above explains the effect and I am off.

Comment: I actually quite like that intuition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.  The energy contained is the same though, as the energy is \$1/2 C V^2\$.  So putting them in series doubles the voltage, but the capacitance must decrease as a result.

Comment: This should explain it all, yes. Always a shame when a sentence beats a story.